# \hat{} symbol "^" in a LaTeX equation in Pages disappears after being exported to a MS Word file

Tags: macos, ms-office, pages, latex

I use Pages 10.2 (7028.0.88) on macOS 10.15.7. As I finished editing my Pages file and exported it to a `.docx` file for my colleagues, all the equations in it were successfully passed to the new file and became editable in MS Word, except that all the `\hat{}`'s "^" were missing.

I also tried `\widehat{}` but encountered the same problem. `\^{}` or `\textrm{\^{}}`, on the other hand, does not work in Pages.

Is there any other LaTeX symbol that looks like `\hat{}` "^" and can stay in the equations after being exported to `.docx`?

Comment: Not sure if there is another form, but your colleague might want to check what format is the equation editor set as in his Microsoft Word. From memory, there’s both Latex and Unicode formats that can be converted. Additionally equation editor in Microsoft Word can autocorrect for any symbols for syntax followed after the ‘\’. I suggest you ask this in the TeX stackexchange